# Networking Ubuntu computers

Tags: 14.04, networking, 18.04

I have recently built a new computer and am running Ubuntu 18.04. I am trying to connect it to another computer (10+ yrs old) running Ubuntu 14.04. The two systems see each other on the network but when it asks for login info it doesn't connect. I have shared the directories but it doesn't seem to help. Any suggestions?

BTW, where do I find the domain of the network?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sharing-personal.html.en). Seems to work good (now that I figured it out.) You can also share other directories beside `Public`, depending on your need for security. Mine is just for home so this works fine.